# Реализация MVC в PHP

Tags: php, ооп

Здравствуйте! Решил написать сайт с использованием MVC. На примере регистрации подскажите, верно ли я уловил суть MVC.
    /// index.php - будет выступать в качестве роутера и подключать необходимые классы и т.п

```
/// registration.class.php
// Класс регистрации 
class Reg
{
 // Проверка на занятость логина
 function check_login($login)
 {
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `login`='{$login}'"); // Вообще буду использовать библиотеку PDO
  $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  return $myrow[0];
  }

  // Регистрация
  function registration($user)
  {
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`,`password`) VALUES ('{$user['login']}','{$user['password']}') ");
    return $result;
  }
}
// Конец класса

/// controller.php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 // Естественно должна идти фильтрация информации от пользователя
 $reg['login'] = $_POST['login'];
 $reg['password'] = $_POST['password'];

 $check_login = $Reg->check_login($reg['login']); // Проверка доступности имени
 if(empty($login)) $error[] = 'Введите логин';
 if(empty($password)) $error[] = 'Введите пароль';
 if($check_login == true) $error[] = 'Логин занят'

 if(!empty($error)
 {
  foreach($error as $value)
  {
    $error_text .= $value;
  }
 }
 else
 {
  $new_user = $Reg->regustration($user); // Регистрируем
  if($new_user == true)
  {
   $_SESSION['id'] = mysql_insert_id();
   header("location: ?action=main";
  }
}
// Здесь показываем шаблон регистрации, например из smarty;
```

Answer (score 7):

Давайте уточним терминологию.
Модель - класс по работе, в простейшем случае, с данными из БД. Модели все равно что будет дальше с этими данными. Ее задача их ДАТЬ.
Представление - классы/функции рендеринга. Представление не знает откуда ему пришли дынные, если иного специально не оговорено(но тогда это тоже чать данных). Его задача нарисовать то, что пришло.
Контроллер - класс, передающий информацию от модели к представлению. Он не знает КАК рисовать и ОТКУДА извлекать данные. Но прекрасно знает КТО может и то и другое. В крайнем случае, он знает у кого спросить.
Он же, в простейшем случае, отвечает за ввод данных и, при необходимости, подключение модели фильтрации, которая не соответствует ни одному представлению.

Роутер - это набор инструментов для правильного определения КОНТРОЛЛЕРА и действия. Все. Стоп. Более он ничем не занимается. Даже __autoload лучше свалить на контроллер.

Дык вот. 
Класс регистрации, положим, это модель. Какая-никакая, но модель.
А вот контроллер у вас занимается слишком большим количеством логики. 
Например, список ошибок он должен прямо так списком и швырнуть представлению.
То же касается занесения данных в сессию и вывода заголовков.

Идеально было бы:

```
$controller = new main_controller();
$user = new user($controller->post('login'),$controller->post('password'));
if($user->logged_user()){
  $view = new your_smarty_render_class($user);
}else{
  $view = new your_smarty_error_render_class($user);
}

class main_controller{
  protected $post;
  function __construct(){
    //Вот это как раз обработка ввода. Можно повесить на еще одну модель
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
      $this->post[$key] = xss_filter($value);
    }
  }
  function post($key){
    return isset($this->post[$key])?$this->post[$key]:false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, если сделать класс - ядро системы, то как раз он и будет запускать сессию, устанавливать локаль и т.п?

Comment: запускать сессию (`session_start()`) может и роутер. А еще лучше - директива auto_session_start.  

А вот класть и извлекать оттуда данные должны модели. Контроллеру это в 99% случаев незачем. Он может и параметры передавать.

Comment: Вы не могли бы привести пример удачной иерархии каталогов на сервере

Comment: Вряд ли. Есть много различных способов это организовать, зависит от задачи.
Стремиться стоит к тому, чтобы различные по сути вещи лежали в различных директориях.

Ядро - в отдельной папке  
Драйвер БД - в отдельной  
Модели - в отдельной и каждая в своей  
Контроллеры - аналогично  
Представления - аналогично  

Кроме того, логику представления и шаблоны тоже хорошо бы разделить.


Есть и другой вариант, отличающийся более простым монтажом новых модулей, но усложняющий поддержку текущих - модуль содержит свою модель, свой контроллер и свое представление со своими шаблонами.

Answer (score 2):

Вот грамотный пример

http://mvcphp.ru/

И видео

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRacpbuG6Es